# Does this mean that the patent has expired, or has it been "un-expired" and now has an adjusted expiration?

Tags: expiration

I was searching patents.google, and I encountered this patent:

[image]

I found this ambiguous, so I just wanted to seek clarification: Does this mean that the patent has indeed expired (fee related), or that it *was* expired (fee related), and "revived" with an adjusted expiration of 2024?

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please clarify this.

Comment: It would make things easier if would link to the patent page.

Comment: Just so you know, it’s possible to make up for a missed fee payment. I assume that is what happened here.

Comment: @EricShain https://patents.google.com/patent/US7123363B2/en?oq=7%2c123%2c363 I'm aware of this. But my point is that it says that the "status" is "Expired - Fee Related", so it's not clear to me whether or not the fee was paid and the patent revived.

Comment: Google patents tries to be helpful, but as George White points out, you really need to consult the Public PAIR site to get authoritative information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get to the bottom of almost any issue with a U.S. patent go to [Public PAIR](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair). The site is fussy about the format of the application number or publication number you enter. I see the expiration due to fee nonpayment but I do *not* see any petition to revive so I would guess that the info panel at google patents is garbled.

Transaction History

Date    Transaction Description

11-14-2014  Expire Patent

01-02-2004  Information Disclosure Statement (IDS) Filed

10-17-2006  Recordation of Patent Grant Mailed

09-27-2006  Issue Notification Mailed

10-17-2006  Patent Issue Date Used in PTA Calculation

09-20-2006  Dispatch to FDC

09-20-2006  Application Is Considered Ready for Issue

Comment: Thanks again, George!

Comment: Is the date this patent was actually expired 11-14-2014? I can't find an explanation for the "Expire Patent" transaction on PAIRS.